# Javascript Call function after window.open

Tags: javascript, load, window

I'm trying to call a function after my window.open function has fully loaded.

However, using the onload function is being called too soon. The URL that's being hit opens an excel spreadsheet and can take from 2 secs to 1 min to download.

The onload function is being called as soon as the window.open function has been called. However, I need to know when the excel doc has been opened - not when the URL was hit.

I've tried setting an interval but that's not being called:

```
w = window.open(url,'_parent',false);   

w.onload = function(){
    console.log('here');
    setInterval(function(){
        alert('Hi');
    },10);
```

Comment: Why not doing this in the child window? And if you don't mind sharing the code that opens the excel file, that would be great - because the excel file load is the real trigger you want..

Comment: do you just want to make sure that excel file open or you need to know exactly when its opened?

Comment: I have an extjs grid sitting behind this that needs to know when the excel file has opened/window has fully loaded the doc. It's a CGI script that is called to open the excel file.

Answer (score 5):

First note that in order to do this without being blocked because of cross-domain restrictions (or without having to parameterize CORS headers on your server), you must :

- serve both your main page and the popup content (your excel file) from the same domain, and the same port
- open your main page in `http://` and not in `file://`

If those conditions are respected, the best solution is to use jquery as its [load](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function waits "until all assets such as images have been completely received" :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<script>
var popup = window.open('popup.html');
$(popup.document).load(function() {
    alert('loaded');
    // do other things
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Be careful with your global scheme : each browser/configuration may do something different when you think they "open" the file. There's no way to detect with a simple `open` if they decided to dismiss it, hadn't the proper plugin, simply downloaded it.

Comment: I am not sure cors headers allows to bypass window origin.