# Triggering window.onload with var window

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'd like to load a page (which I am not hosting/cannot modify) via Javascript, then use Javascript to fill out a form. But of course it can't fill out the form until the form loads. But I don't know how to make it wait until another window loads, not just the window it's running in. For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.ca/");
    myWindow.onload = function(){
    alert("It's loaded!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't ever see the alert "It's loaded!". Is there another function that I need to use for the event of a different window opening, or is there some other way to make this work?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797266/javascript-call-function-after-window-open

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/41905092/5217142  - the timing of `window.onload` events and returning from `window.open` differs between browsers. Please update the question if you have access to the page being loaded to change its source and/or if it is from the same domain.

Comment: Looking at those answers, I tried adding, separately, `$(myWindow.document).load(function () {...});` and `$(myWindow.document).ready(function () {...});`  but neither were triggered. 

I updated the question: I do not have access to the page being loaded to change its source.